# Change the backGroundColor of a row depending on the contents of a several cells in that row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to write a function that will change the backGroundColor of a row depending on the contents of several cells in that row. Here is what I have thus far:

val1 carries the value I need to measure against. rowIndex tells me what row I am on.  How do change the backGroundColor of the current row?

```
function changeBackcolor() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var current = ss.getCurrentCell();
  var rowIndex = current.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = current.getColumnIndex();
  
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var val1 = sheet.getRange(rowIndex,4).getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Changing Background Colors based upon sums of row values

```
function changeBackcolor() {
  const cA = ['#ff000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff', '#ffff00', '#00ffff']
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const rg = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let t = r.reduce((a, c) => {
      a += c;
      return a;
    }, 0);
    sh.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).setBackground(cA[t % cA.length])
  });
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  You the nail on the head! :)